# Securely sandboxing user scripts in a C++ program

Tags: c++, security

I've been working on a personal project in C# whose purpose is more or less to allow the user to execute scripts written by other users and restrict the permissions of that script. My program compiles the scripts using a third-party library, sandboxes them using the .NET Code Access Security mechanisms and makes sure that they have only those permissions that the user wants to give them.

Broadly speaking, my security requirements are:

- the user should be able to restrict the untrusted script's access to only certain parts of the filesystem, including forbidding all filesystem access
- the user should be able to restrict the untrusted script's network connections to only certain IP addresses or hostnames, including forbidding all network connections
- it is okay if the user script manages to hang or terminate the host application, but the user script must not be able to circumvent the permission restrictions (i.e. denial of service is okay, breach isn't)

I'm contemplating trying to do something similar in C++, as a sort of a personal exercise. Obviously, things are more complicated when running native code directly, even if the user scripts are written in a scripting language like Lua.

The first approach I can think of is to insert my own hooks in the scripting environments standard library functions. For example, if the scripting language is Lua, instead of exposing io.open normally, I would have to expose a wrapper that checked the arguments against the script's permissions before passing them to the original implementation.

My concern with this approach is that it drastically increases the amount of my own code that is in charge of security and, therefore, a potential security vulnerability that I wrote myself. In other words, when working with .NET CAS, I can trust that Microsoft did its job well in the sandboxing code, as opposed to having to trust my own sandboxing code.

Are there any alternatives I'm unaware of?

Comment: https://github.com/daveho/EasySandbox

Comment: @RobertHarvey Linux containerization techniques like Seccomp generally only help when running the untrusted code in a separate process, but aren't applicable for in-process isolation. Of course, a fairly simple solution to the problem could include exactly that, a separate process that acts as a service for the main program and only communicates over IPC mechanisms. I wonder if Windows has similar OS-level isolation features?

Comment: @amon: You mean like a... Windows *process?*  Sure it does.

Comment: First off you've introduced the greatest vulnerability into your system already: **Foreign Code**. Everything else is an attempt to mitigate that harm. Essentially you are constructing an interpreter that hopefully executes that foreign code safely. Go and brush up on your [understanding of interpretation](http://matt.might.net/articles/writing-an-interpreter-substitution-denotational-big-step-small-step/) then apply those ideas to enforce the behaviours and relative safety you desire. Secondly do not presume that a sandbox is safe, always add extra layers of defence.

Comment: @Kain0_0 No, I'm not constructing an interpreter. I'm constructing a scriptable application and executing foreign code is basically its purpose. I edited my question to make these things clearer.

Comment: @VojislavStojkovic Can't you just use a javascript engine? By default these engines don't have access to filesystem (not entirely sure about the network but you can check). One example is [QJSEngine](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qjsengine.html#details). Also with these engines you can provide custom c++ code functions to javascript for interoperability.

Comment: @RandomGuy Completely forbidding access for all scripts is not an option. Some user scripts will need to read and write their own files to fulfill their purpose. Others might need to connect to a certain server.

Comment: @VojislavStojkovic You can create C++ code funtions that you can provide to the javascript engine. With this you can customize the access to the filesystem / network based in a login or any other kind of input data.

Comment: @RandomGuy Yep, that's what I outlined in "the first approach I can think of".

Comment: Still not clear here. Are you allowing scripts to execute within your application? *Yes.* Then your are writing an an interpreter. Now you may be using interpreter engines provided by third-parties, but you still have to ground that engine, hence you are at least writing some Denotational aspects - ie. writing a function that provides controlled access to particular resources and presenting it to the interpreter engine. So `Scriptable Application === Interpreter`. My suggestion is that you should apply the full toolbox to convert dubious code into somewhat ratified code.

Comment: That aside, Your choices are 1. using an interpreter engine and provide the grounding, or 2. find a full fledged interpreter application. Either way you need to apply application and OS level controls, which is hard to get right. In .net you were using option 2 just asking the interpreter your code is working in to fork a "process"/App Domain to enforce whatever controls it has. Your challenge there was configuration. If you take option 1. you will be writing code. If you want it to be secure you will need to apply tests, semantic analysis and fuzzing tools. I highly recommend a vm for this.

Answer (score 3):

As others have stated, running foreign code is the greatest issue regarding this sort of implementation. Like Kain0_0's comment suggested, **a VM would be the most appropriate way to maintain foreign code liberty without compromising the host machine** (too much). This is basically what Continuous Integration services like CircleCI do.

This also makes it much easier to implement the interface since you can pull images with all the configuration and security features you want. You also don't have to worry if their code is going to manage to run in your host.

So for this, I would:

- Make snapshots of user script environments I want to cover with [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) (one environment for C#, one for Python, etc, with the appropriate security configurations)
- Upon user request, spin up Docker relevant instances through the code trigger, injecting the foreign script in Docker instance's entrypoint.
- The code is run in the Docker instance with user permissions, files are written, maybe a connection is made here and there, get the output and the environment is then destroyed
- Since Docker containers run as processes, they can be terminated fairly easily i.e. if they exceed a certain time limit. If there's an error, they can terminate immediately.

Basically, have your main code manage the user trigger, entrypoint injection and automated destruction logic for Docker, which is in charge of doing the sandboxing for this sort of operation.

Comment: Great answer. If there is something to add to your answer, it would be that all popular sandbox solutions showed numerous flaws allowing the malicious code to escape its sandbox. This is true for CAS (for instance CVE-2015-2504), and even more true for Java (exploits for browser Java plugin too numerous to list here). While Docker does have vulnerabilities too, I have an impression that the attack surface is much lower compared to anything implemented at the level of a given language/framework.